# How do I reset my Tiny Death Star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've been looking all over the app every option, etc. and I can't find a way to reset my Death Star. I even deleted and re-installed the app. I have not saved to Facebook, as I don't have one. How do I reset it?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you'd add the device you are playing on.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the app's data. This will delete your saves without deleting the app itself (since re-installing it downloads your cloud data). The way to do this would depend on your device.

If that doesn't work, delete the data then start Tiny Death Star without an internet connection. This will force it to begin a new game and, even if it does acquire your cloud save later, you will have the option to keep it.